# How to block HTTP access to file

Tags: php, iis

I have a Microsoft-IIS server.
I have a file named "log.txt" on the server.

How can i block http access to this file, but allow PHP to edit him?

Thanks.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/72680/iis7-how-to-block-access-with-a-web-config-file

Comment: Do you mean a php script that is run as a result of an HTTP request?

Answer (score 2):

Place your log file into its own folder, and then you can write a `.htaccess` file in there to further prevent access to it. It'll still allow your server-side stuff 
(php, for example) to read/write to it still, but prevent others.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Comment: When you created the .htaccess file, where did you place the file at? Make sure you didn't place an extension on the end of it when you created/saved it. Are you running the server yourself? Have access directly to the server? Using a host? Throw some info my way and I'll be happy to help you out further with it.

Answer (score 0):

This code will block acess to `log.txt`

```
<location path="log.txt">
     <system.webServer>
         <security>
             <authorization>
                 <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                 <add accessType="Allow" roles="Administrators" />
             </authorization>
         </security>
     </system.webServer>
 </location>
```

Detailed answer on [servervault](https://serverfault.com/questions/72680/iis7-how-to-block-access-with-a-web-config-file)

Comment: That's blocking access to all the files on the server.